# Content not visible on IOS

Tags: ios, vue.js, scroll

I am having issues with something on my website. I wanted to make a timepicker and it worked well on my laptop but as soon as i test it on my phone it breaks the timepicker. This website should only work for Mobile and i noticed that this problem only occurs on IOS. Does anyone know what the problem might be? I will leave images to make the problem visual. Thanks for your suggestions [On laptop but with Mobile mode activated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F7tDO.png) [On IOS no time visible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0xT5m.jpg)

Comment: Please edit your question to include the relevant code, the section with the time picker. We will need to look at the code to try and help you solve the issue.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.